# (Tomcat) Backup WAR on Deploy

Tags: tomcat

Are there any built in mechanisms to backup a war file on deploy in Tomcat?

For example, I deploy whosit.war. I want the current whosit.war that's deployed to backup to whosit-backup.war. Or if each deploy kept an extra copy of the deploy at whosit-deploy-20110317-211037.war. etc etc.

Obviously I could add this to my deploy script but it would make my life so nice if Tomcat did anything like the above.

Comment: Backup?  Shouldn't you be able to create one at will by checking out your tagged branch from Subversion or Git?  A backup copy is good, but versioned source is better.

Comment: I have my source in HG (pssh on your svn) so I'm all set there. It is not the end of the world but I would _like_ a backup copy just for that 0.000001% of the time when something goes horribly wrong and it would be _nice_ to quickly move a good copy of the war back in place instead of cloning a tag, rebuilding and deploying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [tag a deploy when deploying a webapp remotely](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely) by specifying the `tag` attribute. If you're using Maven you can [specify the tag with the tomcat-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#tag). Assuming you already have the plugin setup you need only to specify the property. Example:

```
<properties>
    <maven.tomcat.url>http://example.com:8080/manager</maven.tomcat.url>
    <tomcat.username>tomcat</tomcat.username>
    <tomcat.password>tomcat</tomcat.password>
    <maven.tomcat.tag>mytag</maven.tomcat.tag>
    <maven.tomcat.path>/myapp</maven.tomcat.path>
</properties>
```

This will create a copy of the war in the work directory of your manager in a directory named after your tag (e.g. `$CATALINA_HOME/work/Catalina/localhost/manager/mytag`). You can retrieve and redeploy this war through the manager by specifying the `path` and `tag`:

```
http://example.com:8080/manager/deploy?path=/myapp&tag=mytag
```

Note: if the manager work directory ever gets deleted then your tagged deploys will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to script this up yourself.