# Backup deployed web application before deploying new version (automatically)

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, backup

Here's the situation:

I'm using maven along with cargo plugin to automatically deploy web apps to different environments, using Hudson to run/schedule jobs to do the work. I'm using tomcat as a target app container.

But I'd like to find the best way to backup the deployed web application to some network/FTP location, before maven/cargo deploy latest version. I have been looking for some maven plugin that helps to do something similar, but seems like tasks like this are out of the scope of maven. Also I'm searching for some Hudson plugin that may helps to do this work, but without success.

I also took a look at the discussion in [(Tomcat) Backup WAR on Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227551/tomcat-backup-war-on-deploy), but what I want to avoid is someone going and take the war file from tomcat and place it into the external location, I'd like to automate this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to define maven-antrun-plugin on the prepare-package phase or the package phase.
See the list of phases: 
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-structure.html#lifecycle-sect-default
Then, create the ant target that copy you war to any place.

Here the example of the maven-antrun-plugin on phase install:

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>file-exists</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <exec executable="cmd">
                                    <arg value="/c"/>
                                    <arg value="copy your file"/>
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then, create the ant target that copy you war to any place. 
You can use other task instead of exec task, for example SCP task: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html
Also, you can define your own maven profile that will be invoked only in Hudson.

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks

Comment: yes, sorry the delay, I've tested it and work pretty fine, Thanks !! =)

Comment: Sorry the delay, I got busy with some other tasks, yesterday I started to test your proposal, I just need to run some other scenarios from Jenkins, and maybe to tune the ant task, but at least I know to approach what want to do, thanks.